# What is the best way to sanitize data?

Tags: sanitization, wpdb

I've read several topics about this and different people have different views on the best practice.

In terms of WordPress, how do I write data to the database the safest way?

This is one insert I'm using now:

```
$result = $wpdb->insert(
    $table_name , 
    array( 
        'arena'         => $galleryData['arena'],
        'year'          => substr( $galleryData['season'], 2 ),
        'copyright'     => $galleryData['copyright'],
        'description'   => $galleryData['description'],
        'path'          => $galleryData['path'],
        'fk_brand_id'   => $galleryData['brand']
    ), 
    array( '%s', '%d', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%d' )
);
```

Another way of inserting data is doing this:

```
$sanitized_sql = $wpdb->prepare( "
    INSERT INTO my_plugin_table 
    SET 
        field1 = %1$d,
        field2 = %2$s,
        field3 = %3$s’,
        32, 
        'Aaron Brazell',
        'Washington, D.C'
" );
$wpdb->query( $sanitized_sql );
```

Do I still need to sanitize data using [`wp_kses()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses) or [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)?

I'm just confused on what method is the better for safely writing data to the database. I found a helpful [answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127009/using-wordpress-can-some-one-tell-me-the-best-way-of-sanitizing-input).

**So should I or should I not sanitize data before input?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No the sanitization is already done. Well the [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) is done, it's considered bad form to filter html on input. I personally think doing it on output kinda breaches DRY. If you did in WordPress I highly suspect somewhere else will do it again resulting in double html entities encoding.

Also by the way, wpdb::insert is basically just a wrapper for wpdb::prepare.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. So there is no real point in using `wp_kses` before storing data to DB? Or any other filter found here? http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation

Comment: Well I guess it really depends what you're doing with the data. If you're handling it yourself completely then good form is to do it on output.

Answer (score 4):

Note that **storing data safely** is different from **safe data**. For example JavaScript code can be totally harmless in context of database security, but nightmare in context of front-end.

There is no single blanket approach, that is why [WordPress has massive amount of related functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation).

You must consider:

1. What data is.
2. Where it comes from.
3. How is it going to be used.

Comment: Do you have any good references for point 1-3? I've seen the Data Validation page - that's what I've been using so far. But I'm still unsure of what is better practice for storing / retrieving data the safest way inputed by users.

Comment: @Steven well, that page is quite comprehensive in context of WP. Most important point is at start - " **untrusted** data [..] needs to be validated both on **input** and **output** ". So you need to sanitize untrusted data when it goes to database (`->prepare()` and such) and when it goes to display (`esc_` and such).