# prevent post submission

Tags: metabox, actions, save-post

I'm using a meta-box for custom post type. I have three problems:

1. WP seems to run the function that I attached to the "save_post" action, every time a new post is opened for editing or reloaded. Is there a way to prevent it from running?
2. WP saves the post even when I add "return false" after validation fails. Is there another way of doing it?
3. how can I validate the built-in WP title field? (I assume it is sent as $_POST['something'])

TIA for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the Codex, on [save_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post). In answer to Question 1, it is fired whenever WordPress auto_saves a revision (i.e. hence when a post is edited). In particular, when creating a new post, `wp-admin/post-new.php` is loaded. WordPress then creates an auto draft even if you haven't saved a draft or published to post. This is intended as it means stuff like the media uploads functions properly.

*You shouldn't try to prevent it from running*, but instead, check in your hooked function that it is not an auto-save routine:

```
add_action('save_post','my_save_function');
function my_save_function($post_id) {

    //You should have a nonce to check the data came from your metabox

    // verify this is not an auto save routine. 
    if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

    //Or: if (wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) return;

    //perform authentication checks
    if (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) return;

    $raw_data = $_POST['name_of_input_field'];
    //Sanitise your data
    }
```

In answer to Q2: returning false in the above function doesn't prevent the post saving. This is because WordPress just fires the action 'save_post' but does not consider any returns from it, and proceeds to save the post (**EDIT:** In fact, `save_post` is called after the post is inserted into the database).

You *could* 'exit' the process, like [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16372/prevent-publishing-the-post-before-setting-a-featured-image), but if you want to check the metabox has been filled in, I suggest using jQuery instead. If you wish to display an error notice if your metabox wasn't correctly filled in, [see this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15354/passing-error-warning-messages-from-a-meta-box-to-admin-notices).

I'm not sure why you are asking Q3 - WordPress handles the sanitisation of stuff like the title before it saves it to the database - you don't have to worry about that. Or are you wanting to use the title in a custom field?

In short though, so long as you use something like [`update_post_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) to save data to the database, you don't need to escape the data. But with regards to which checks you should perform prior to that depends on what you are willing to except as the data input. On output you should be escaping data - but quite how again depends on context. [See this post.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8040/what-is-the-best-way-to-sanitize-data)

Comment: Thx for the detailed answer. as for Q1, i'm already using an if statement to escape the auto-save, but for some reason it's still firing on new\edit post. Q3: the reason i'd like to deal with the title is that WP allows the user to save a post without a title, and i don't want to allow it.

Comment: By the time `save_post` is called the post has already been inserted into the database. You could use jQuery to prevent the post from being submitted in the case that a title isn't entered. The above function in my answer will be called with a new/edit post, its just won't do anything. If it's not working for you, edit your question to include the code and someone may be able to help.

Comment: You don’t need to return `$post_id`. `do_action()` doesn’t expect a return value.

Comment: You're right. But I did need to exit the function. Just habit I suppose :D